# Suppressing Possible null reference exception message from Resharper on a asp.net mvc view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resharper, nullreferenceexception

consider code like this:

```
[HttpPost]   
     public ActionResult Index(TestModel testModel)
    {
        //ReSharper PossibleNullReferenceException message appears on the testModel
        var x = testModel.Name;
        return View(testModel);
    }
```

Is there a better way to tell Resharper that the testModel can never be null.I want  to avoid placing Debug.Assert,If null throw etc all over my action methods it seems too verbose.
This also applies to my service variable( I am using dependecy injection,_myService.blah etc) .I love the green Resharper tick(no errors or warings) on the class that tells me I have handled all null references and code correctness.But if I ignore the messages I do not get the green tick.

How do you guys deal with this, do you suppress the message with a comment, place if null throw,add debug assert(this just makes code a bit too verbose for things that you can assume can never be null.

**NOTE:** I do not want to switch off null reference checking( I have set them to warnings).

Comment: If you don't mind more pervasiveness, see `[NotNull]`. If it `[CanBeNull]` (or unspecified with the given settings) then you'll have to add a guard (or comment-suppress the warning or use external annotions) to make R# happy. (My code is highly annotated, but NotNull is a double-edged sword precisely because it *can* suppress warnings on invalid assumptions and is applied to both the outside API and the implementation - thus, for all public methods I also have an if-throw guard on arguments which might yield and NRE.)

Comment: Yes I have thought about using [NotNull] but it just sometimes does not feel right as you suggested that you might suppress warnings on invalid assumptions.I am just wondering if everybody is using the [NotNull] on their action methods.I am particularly interested with MVC  action methods.Do devs ignore the warnings put if then throws etc.I dont mind adding if null throw... to my service methods.

Comment: I would add [NotNull] *and* an if-null-then-throw in this particular case (because it's a public/outward API). If there is a guarantee that the value can never be null (check the assumption) then the null check can be omitted and the [NotNull] will still take care of the R# warning. Basically - how much is the caller trusted? (I wish R# had outward and inward NN annotations..)

Comment: [NotNull] and an if-null-then-throw  is the way to go.I have made my methods small so that its not that annoying to see a throw.I am still experimenting.My code is also becoming highly annotated.BTW I am using ReSharper default "pessimistic null checking".Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, it sounds like you have turned on "pessimistic null checking" in ReSharper, where it assumes everything that is not explicitly checked for null, or marked with `[NotNull]` is null. By default, ReSharper uses the "optimistic" approach, where if you're not *explicitly* checking for null or marking the entity with `[CanBeNull]` attribute, ReSharper won't flag it.

You want to be using the optimistic mode, make sure it's enabled by going to **Code Inspection → Settings** in ReSharper Options, and making sure the highlighted entry is selected:
[image]

This should reduce the number of possible null reference warnings significantly!

Comment: Thanks but that is what I want to really avoid , I want those messages, I do  not want to assume.Things that are a bit obvious like _myservice variables that are injected lets say by Ninject , I know Ninject will complain if I dont supply the a non null _myService etc  and model binding will make sure the value for the model as parameter is never null(unless something strange happens to model binding)

Comment: But it seems that you turned on the explicit null checking everywhere! By default, the piece of code you pasted does *not*, in fact, warn about `TestModel` being null. Most of the time it won't be (provided everything is wired properly). Checking for null everywhere is actually quite the opposite of what you want - it makes debugging harder. So first, make sure you're using the default setting (as on the image above). Otherwise you have to do explicit null checks or mark things with [NotNull] attribute yourself.

Comment: You are right that it does reduce , but I noticed the setting also switches of null checking for eg  var x = testModel.Name.Trim();it doesnt put a warning to tell me a possible null reference on testModel.Name but if I leave it as "When Entity doesn’t have explicit NotNull attribute." it shows the warning.I would rather have those warnings .But for testModel it should not because model binding will make sure it will not be null.Maybe I should just check for if(testModel) is null throw, it seems I have no choice because I like those Resharper green ticks